# Trigger external remote script

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops

I have a powershell script located on a different server, and I want to trigger this script from the build server(TFS 2018) using a network path.

```
//MyServer/MyScripts/run.ps1
```

In the Powershell build step I need to specify script path under TFS source path. Is there a way to trigger the external script?

This is what I've tried without success....

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName MyServer -ScriptBlock {Get-Process -Name //MyServer/MyScripts/run.ps1} -ArgumentList 'arg1', 'arg2'
```

Comment: Get-process get's an existing process. If I understand then you want to start a new process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -scriptblock {Pushd $rootFolder
                .\$scriptname.ps1}
```

Or you could Invoke-Command -FilePath

Depends on where you want to run it.

Comment: Thanks @Jewtus I am pretty new to PowerShell, I edited the question with a code sample where I am trying to call the powershell script directly on the server. Could you give an example using the example values how you do this using your suggestion with Invoke-Comman. I assume I will put this code inside the build step which then calls the script on the server?

Comment: So it worked like this Invoke-Command -FilePath \\MyRemoteServer\Scripts\run.ps1 -ComputerName MyRemoteServer -ArgumentList 'arg1', 'arg2'

Comment: Yea, when you use Scriptblock, you need to put a PARAM() in the beginning to catch the args. Its better to use the -Computername -Filename -Argumentlist if you have a file and -scriptblock if you are just trying to fire a small part of code remotely (ex a command for get-printers or something)